# Debian boot hangs

Tags: linux, boot, debian, kernel

I created a Debian USB stick image from the experimental repo with the latest kernel 3.15 RC8, used Syslinux. I wrote the image on a USB stick and I booted from it on two different computers.

On the first PC, Debian boots just fine.

However, on the second one, the boot hangs at the following point:

[image: photograph of screen with boot messages]

Then I mounted the USB stick to the PC which I used for image creation, and checked all the log files in /var/log. I cannot find any log entry according to the second PC. I truncated all the log files, then I tried to boot from this stick on the second PC again. Of course it hung at the very same point. I remounted the USB stick and checked the log files. They were all empty. So it seems I cannot track what is going on this way.

Does anyone have any ideas, what is the problem here? Or at least how can I analyze the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when a system hangs while writing boot messages to the screen such as in your image, it's not the last line on the screen that gives a clue as to what is going wrong, but the next one, that hasn't been written yet.

On the machine that successfully boots, do you get the "NX-protecting" and "dracut:" lines in the boot messages?  If so, what is the next line?  This might give you a path to analyze the problem.

If the boot messages scroll past too fast, use:

```
dmesg|less
```

or:

```
dmesg|more
```

in a terminal to view them again.

Comment: Thank you for the response. These are the lines that following the "NX Compat line":
`[    1.326352] NX-protecting the kernel data: 3908k
[    1.370250] dracut: dracut-7 (wheezy) dracut-
[    1.408506] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    1.408808] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.27.0-ioctl (2013-10-30) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    1.418558] udevd[99]: starting version 175
[    1.649446] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    1.649724] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.649926] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub`